# Распаковка архивов из smart install maker

Tags: установка, zip

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой при использовании smart install maker. Допустим у меня есть zip-архив с компонентами программы. Я создаю для него инсталлер в sim. Возможно ли заставить sim распаковать zip? Сторонний софт использовать нельзя, тк он может не оказаться на компьютере.

Comment: можно сделать самораспаковывающийся архив с помощью winrar.
http://win-rar.softkey.ru/support/knowledge/detail.php?ID=997

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать самораспаковывающийся sfx архив с помощью winrar.

http://win-rar.softkey.ru/support/knowledge/detail.php?ID=997

Comment: Мне нужно именно smart im. Возможно есть команда в консоли, которая сможет разархивировать файлы?